# How to give both handleSubmit and function to one onPress?

Tags: react-native

I use `react-native`.

I have `TouchableOpacity` named SmallButton below.
and if you see `onPress`, I give `handleSubmit` when it is pressed.

```
<SmallButton
  styleB={{ backgroundColor: `${colors.normal}` }}
  styleBT={{ color: `${colors.lightgray}`, fontSize: 20 }}
  text={"확인"}
  onPress={handleSubmit(EditValid)} // want to add navigate.goBack()
/>
```

it works well.

but my question is I want to `navigate.goBack()` after `handleSubmit`.
But don't know how.

First I wanted to make one function like

```
const onClick = () => {
 handleSubmit(EditValid);
 navigation.goBack()
}
```

then `onPress={onClick}`.

but of course since `handleSubmit` is not a `function`, this handleSubmit doesn't work.

How to make it work handleSubmit and navigation both in 1 onPress?

Comment: 'handleSubmit is not a function'. Could you share the code for your `handleSubmit`?

Comment: @DavidScholz - handleSubmit is `reactHooks` that I use, which is `useForm()`. like this :   const { register, setValue, handleSubmit } = useForm();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming EditValid is a custom function made by you, so you can call navigation.goBack() in it.